# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UIPageViewControllerDelegate'?

Tags: ios, xcode

This code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "MessageComposerViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> // Add the delegate

- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;

{
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

This problem or error :

- Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UIPageViewControllerDelegate'?
  for this lign : #import "MessageComposerViewController.h"
- Expected identifier or '('
  for this lign : @interface MapViewController : UIViewController  // Add the delegate
  and this lign : {

Thanks for advance. :)

Comment: @interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
it will work.

Comment: Now : Expected identifier or '(' for this : {
Just after "- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;"

Comment: Well, you should declare your ivars first, then your properties, then your methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This,

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
    #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
    #import "MessageComposerViewController.h"
    #import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

    @interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
      IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
   }
    - (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView; 
    @end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do the above and still see the warning in Xcode, try building or building & running your app. Sometimes these warnings linger after you've addressed the problem and are cleared out by a compilation cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today coding an app for ios8.
First thing that I did was re-add the framework, but it didn't help. The problem was I ignored libAWDProtobufFacetimeiMessage - a protocol buffer file. I'm no professional to guess why, but when I added both buffer and the framework itself, the error message disappeared. I have posted a screenshot [here](http://i.piccy.info/i9/4b08f713e3485e495d6d625e5202e8e2/1408537563/57872/720071/Screen_Shot_2014_08_20_at_3_22_16.png). Hope my answer helps anyone looking here in the future.

Comment: @roo This does not appear to be a question.